# Numpy: get the lowest N elements of an array X, considering only elements whose index is not an element in another array Y

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

To get the lowest 10 values of an array X I do something like:

```
lowest10 = np.argsort(X)[:10]
```

what is the most efficient way, avoiding loops, to filter the results so that I get the lowest 10 values whose index is not an element of another array Y?

So for example if the array Y is:

```
[2,20,51]
```

X[2], X[20] and X[51] shouldn't be taken into consideration to compute the lowest 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
sidx = X.argsort()
idx_out = sidx[~np.in1d(sidx, Y)][:10]
```

Sample run -

```
# Setup inputs
In [141]: X = np.random.choice(range(60), 60)

In [142]: Y = np.array([2,20,51])

# For testing, let's set the Y positions as 0s and 
# we want to see them skipped in o/p
In [143]: X[Y] = 0

# Use proposed approach
In [144]: sidx = X.argsort()

In [145]: X[sidx[~np.in1d(sidx, Y)][:10]]
Out[145]: array([ 0,  2,  4,  5,  5,  9,  9, 10, 12, 14])

# Print the first 13 numbers and skip three 0s and 
# that should match up with the output from proposed approach
In [146]: np.sort(X)[:13]
Out[146]: array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  4,  5,  5,  9,  9, 10, 12, 14])
```

Alternatively, for performance, we might want to use `np.argpartition`, like so -

```
sidx = np.argpartition(X,range(10+Y.size))
idx_out = X[sidx[~np.in1d(sidx, Y)][:10]]
```

This would be beneficial if the length of `X` is a much larger number than `10`.

If you don't care about the order of elements in that list of `10` indices, for further boost, we can simply pass on the scalar length instead of `range` array to `np.argpartition` : `np.argpartition(X,10+Y.size)`.

We can optimize `np.in1d` with `searchsorted` to have one more approach (listing next).

---

Listing below all the discussed approaches in this post -

```
def app1(X, Y, n=10):
    sidx = X.argsort()
    return sidx[~np.in1d(sidx, Y)][:n]

def app2(X, Y, n=10):
    sidx = np.argpartition(X,range(n+Y.size))
    return sidx[~np.in1d(sidx, Y)][:n]

def app3(X, Y, n=10):
    sidx = np.argpartition(X,n+Y.size)
    return sidx[~np.in1d(sidx, Y)][:n]


def app4(X, Y, n=10):
    n_ext = n+Y.size
    sidx = np.argpartition(X,np.arange(n_ext))[:n_ext]
    ssidx = sidx.argsort()
    mask = np.ones(ssidx.size,dtype=bool)
    search_idx = np.searchsorted(sidx, Y, sorter=ssidx)
    search_idx[search_idx==sidx.size] = 0
    idx = ssidx[search_idx]    
    mask[idx[sidx[idx] == Y]] = 0
    return sidx[mask][:n]
```

Comment: Hi. I made the inevitable benchmarks, but I'm  not sure I picked your best. And on top of that our results are different. Could you have a look and check if I set up everything correctly?

Comment: @PaulPanzer `argsort`'s order would be random for the identical elements and as such would be different than with `argparitition`. So, I would say index into `X` and then do value verification. Hope that clears out your doubts.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Oh wait, you are indexing into `X` for verification, right?

Comment: I'm doing that already. The `X`'s are different. I'm too tired to think right now. Will fix it later. Cheers.

Comment: I think I know what's wrong. I think you are counting all `Y` as shifting up "valid" `sidx` where you should only count those that are really included in `sidx`. The `+Y.size` will - given the numbers - typically contain no or few `Y`. Make sense?

Comment: Your other three agree and agree with mine.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Fixed mine. Thanks for pointing it out! That arsgort on top of argpartition was a smart move in your solution!

Comment: SIgh, another secret weapon not so secret anymore. I need all of them to keep up with your pace. -- Yeah, I was surprised how poorly `argpartition` performs with a range argument. Maybe it's more meant for dispersed split points?

Comment: @PaulPanzer That could be it! But I never really realised its slowness with that range param.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answers guys. I accepted Divakar's (also because was the first one) and upvoted @PaulPanzer's

Answer (score 2):

After some benchmarking here is my humble recommendation:

Swapping out appears to be more or less always faster than masking (even if 99% of X are forbidden.) So use something along the lines of

```
swap = X[Y]
X[Y] = np.inf
```

Sorting is expensive, therefore use `argpartition` and only sort what's necessary. Like

```
lowest10 = np.argpartition(Xfiltered, 10)[:10]
lowest10 = lowest10[np.argsort(Xfiltered[lowest10])]
```

Here are some benchmarks:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def swap_out():
    global sol

    swap = X[Y]
    X[Y] = np.inf

    sol = np.argpartition(X, K)[:K]
    sol = sol[np.argsort(X[sol])]

    X[Y] = swap

def app1():
    sidx = X.argsort()
    return sidx[~np.in1d(sidx, Y)][:K]

def app2():
    sidx = np.argpartition(X,range(K+Y.size))
    return sidx[~np.in1d(sidx, Y)][:K]

def app3():
    sidx = np.argpartition(X,K+Y.size)
    return sidx[~np.in1d(sidx, Y)][:K]


K = 10    # number of small elements wanted
N = 10000 # size of X
M = 10    # size of Y
S = 10    # number of repeats in benchmark

X = np.random.random((N,))
Y = np.random.choice(N, (M,))

so = timeit(swap_out, number=S)
print(sol)
print(X[sol])
d1 = timeit(app1, number=S)
print(sol)
print(X[sol])
d2 = timeit(app2, number=S)
print(sol)
print(X[sol])
d3 = timeit(app3, number=S)
print(sol)
print(X[sol])

print('pp', f'{so:8.5f}', '  d1(um)', f'{d1:8.5f}', '  d2', f'{d2:8.5f}', '  d3', f'{d3:8.5f}')
# pp  0.00053   d1(um)  0.00731   d2  0.00313   d3  0.00149
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work on a subset of original array using [numpy.delete()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html);

```
lowest10 = np.argsort(np.delete(X, Y))[:10]
```

Since delete works by slicing the original array with indexes to keep, complexity should be constant.

---

Warning: This solution uses a subset of original *X* array (X without the elements indexed in Y), thus the end result will be the lowest 10 of that subset.

Comment: But that `np.argsort(np.delete(X, Y))` would get `argsort` corresponding to the deleted `X` and as such those argsort won't correspond to the original X. So, to get the correct result of lowest 10 values from `X`, we need to use your `lowest10` to index into deleted `X` and not `X`. This might be worth a mention in the post.

Comment: Yeah, I have written this on the premise of OP's last sentence _"... shouldn't be taken into consideration to compute the lowest 10"_. But if this is going to be used in some solution, that is a good point. I'll add a disclaimer, thanks.